# Error with migrating my Chrome Extension to Manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to migrate my Chrome Extension to manifest V3.
The content_security policy looks as follows on manifest V2:

{...
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' **'sha256-...'**; object-src 'self'"
}

Notice that I'm using sha-256 value which is the most specific property.
Furthermore, I performed a "semi-official" converting using [this tool](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/extension-manifest-converter/).

When I convert the manifest to V3 and then update the extension, I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8drLO.png). I don't understand why it is considered as an insecure CSP value, while it is accepted on Manifest V2 and is considered secure to use the specified hash value of the code.
How can I overcome it?

Comment: Quite interesting that the "semi-official" tool doesn't work, but not surprised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In manifest MV3, CSP is an object, however in the error it is a string, so it needs to be reformatted.

---

Example and instructions from [migration guide:](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy)

**Manifest V2**

```
"content_security_policy": "..."
```

**Manifest V3**

```
"content_security_policy": {
  "extension_pages": "...",
  "sandbox": "..."
}
```

- **extension_pages**: This policy covers pages in your extension, including html files and service workers. 
  These page types are served from the `chrome-extension://` protocol. For instance, a page in your extension is `chrome-extension://<extension-id>/foo.html`.
- **sandbox**: This policy covers any [sandboxed extension pages](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/) that your extension uses.

**Important!**

In addition, MV3 disallows certain CSP modifications for extension_pages that were permitted in MV2. The script-src, object-src, and worker-src directives may only have the following values:

- self
- none
- Any localhost source, (http://localhost, http://127.0.0.1, or any port on those domains)

CSP modifications for sandbox have no such new restrictions.

---

Going through this guide, it seems having sha-256 values is not allowed for extension pages. But these are typically inlined scripts. You can save the script as a js file, and load it from there using `<script/>` tag instead; this will not require CSP policy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative annecdote!
Regarding your solutions for replacing the unsupported sha-256 value:
My whole extension is designed with react-app and therefore I always build it before launching it at the browser so all of the code hierarchy is one big mess. What is your suggestion regarding executing the whole build-up application without the usage of the hash value of the code?

Comment: Use a js file, and load it using script tag, then CSP is not needed. It may require writing a custom script to automate this step.